# How to learn timeseries with LSTM, having different orders of magnitude in the output?

Tags: machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I am relatively new to neural networks and LSTM networks in particular, but I already worked with other ML algorithms.

I am currently trying to reproduce a physical model (based on ordinary differential equations) with a Long-Short Term Memory network. In practice, I ran the original model several times, for different values of its parameters, obtaining different datasets that I am now using for test and validation. In general, my problem can be expressed as:

y = f(t, k, s)

where **t** is the input (time), **k** is a parameter that does not change during the same time series, and **s** is the state of the system.

My issues are related to the behavior of the system for different values of **k**: not only the values of **y** vary by orders of magnitudes, but the peaks of the function also appear much sooner or later, also depending on **k**. To give you an example, here are two time series for values of **k=3**:

[image]

and **k=6**:

[image]

You might notice that not only the peak values of **y** differ by an order of magnitude, but the peaks appear at very different instants of **t** (close to **t=0.02** for **k=3**, close to **t=0.1** for **k=6**).

Summing up, I have two questions:

a) if I normalize **y**, training the LSTM network provides good results for higher values of **k**, and lousy results for low values of **k**, probably because the optimization greatly reduces the error by overfitting the time series for high values of **k**. Is there a way to assign the same importance to each time series, regardless of the peak values of **y**?

b) Sampling the time series is also an issue: if I sample all time series using the same value of delta_t (to define the time interval between samples), I end up with very few points for time series with low **k**, or (vice-versa) with a lot of points for each time series, and huge datasets that slow down training considerably. Do you have any advice? Is choosing a different delta_t for each time series a viable option?